# Embed a executable inside another executable

Tags: unix

Is it possible embed a binary file inside another binary file in UNIX/Linux.

This is certainly possible in Windows using Win32 API. [Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2009/10/16/how-to-embed-an-exe-inside-another-exe-as-a.aspx)

Comment: A binary file inside a binary file is just a binary file. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967

Comment: The article explains how to embed and access, but not how to execute the embedded data.

Comment: @avrono I want to use few features which are present in another application but I want to ship only one binary file. So, If I can embed the other binary file inside my application, I can use that feature by executing that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the purpose is. Nothing prevents one from creating an executable that incorporates another executable as a binary blob. [Sharutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/) does exactly that (except that the outer program is a shell script, not a binary).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is easy to embed text or binary files inside another (text/binary) file on Unix/Linux.  Tar, shar archives, gzip, and even cat would work.  You could place the entire binary image into a variable in your executable.

Do you prefer a single file that does Everything(tm), or a self-extracting file that extracts all the associated files?  Because you can certainly do either.  But the Unix idiom is more to provide a single archive file (tar, gzip, etc), extract the file, and then install the extracted file.